# JQuery mouseenter affecting group of elements instead of $(this) element

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a group of elements which on hover, I want to increase the padding of that element and not the group of elements.

This is the HTML of the page.

```
<div id="share-article-container">
    <div id="share-article">
    <?php include('share_article_content.php');?>    
    </div>
    <div id="share-bubbles">
        <div id="link-bubble" style="margin-top:55px" class="bubble"><span style="position: absolute;margin-left:5px;text-align:center;font-size:20px;">Copiar enlace</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the file share_article_content.php

```
<a style="background:#25D366" target="_blank" href="https://wa.me/?text=<?php echo urlencode('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])?>"><img style="height:25px" src="images/whatsapp_icons/WhatsApp_Logo_2.png"></a>
<a onclick="copyToClipboard()" id="share-article-link"><i style="color:white;font-size:25px;" class="fas fa-link"></i></a>
<a style="background:#1778f2" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo urlencode('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])?>" target="_blank"><img style="height:25px;" src="images/facebook_icons/logo.png"></a>
<a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=<?php echo urlencode('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])?>"><img style="height:25px;" src="images/twitter_icons/twitter-xxl.png"></a>
<a href = "mailto:abc@example.com?subject=<?php echo ucwords($title)?>&body=<?php echo urlencode('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])?>" style="background:red;"><i style="color:white;font-size:25px;" class="far fa-envelope"></i></a>
```

This is the CSS for these elements:

```
#share-article a{
   display: block;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 5px;
   transition: 0.5s;
}
```

And this is the JQuery I'm using to solve this:

```
$("#share-article").on("mouseenter", "a", function(){
    $(this).css("width", "70px");
});

$("#share-article").on("mouseleave","a", function(){
    $(this).css("width", "50px");
});
```

When I attempt this with the shown code this is what happens:

Not on hover:

[image]

Hovering on Whatsapp:

[image]

All elements are being affected, but I want only the element being hovered to be affected.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `a img` selector without `$()` .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("#share-article").on("mouseenter", "img", function() {
  $(this).css("width", "70px");
});

$("#share-article").on("mouseleave", "img", function() {
  $(this).css("width", "50px");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="share-article-container">
  <div id="share-article">
    <div>
      <a style="background:#25D366" target="_blank" href=""><img style="height:50px" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/25/07/28/2507288cc5191483075bc6aba6771aa3.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a style="background:#25D366" target="_blank" href=""><img style="height:50px" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQOah0u5VksX76TPAhx-0HUHurBXuDkhAndAw&usqp=CAU"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="share-bubbles">
    <div id="link-bubble" style="margin-top:55px" class="bubble"><span style="position: absolute;margin-left:5px;text-align:center;font-size:20px;">Copiar enlace</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The rest of the elements are adapting their padding to the new width of the hovered element

Comment: now check if that work for you . I have just added `outer div` to a tag to separate them .

Comment: It doesn't make any difference

Comment: I think i misunderstood your question . You need to increase padding or width ?

Comment: I want to increase the width of the ´a´ element on hover without affecting the others. Your code snippet would be fine if it increased the width of the ´a´ element. Despite this when I apply your code to my website it doesn't work.

Comment: can you show that behaviour ? is your website live somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

I was changing the width of the `a` element without having an initial width.

```
#share-article a{
   display: block;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 5px;
   transition: 0.5s;
   width: 50px
}
```

The problem was not having the width set in the first place. Once it was added the JQuery worked fine.